# User posting same answer to different questions

Tags: discussion, answers, duplicate-answers

Today, while reviewing the Late Answers queue, a strange event happened.

I was presented [a post](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/12316202) to review from a user. I edited the answer and clicked *I'm Done*, but the [next review post](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/12316204) was the same post from the same user and the edit which I made was not visible.

After checking I observed that the specific user was posting the same answer to different questions.

Should I flag all the answers or only one? Which flag should I use?

Comment: That user has posted the same answer three times ([one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37161808/464709), [two](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37161876/464709), [three](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37161726/464709)). You may want to flag one of those posts for moderator attention so they can give a gentle nudge to the user in question.

Comment: The user actually has three of the exact same post.  AFAIK a auto mod flag is raised if a user post an exact copy on another question.